# 404 – Not Found from _entry.twig templates in subdirectories

Tags: templating, error

Following the Minjingo CraftQuest tutorial, I am getting an error on the front end when I access any routes other than the root/home page.

In my template folder, I have a structure that looks like:

```
templates/
├── index.twig
├── about/
│   └── _entry.twig
├── drinks/
│   └── _entry.twig
└── news/
    └── _entry.twig
```

In my about section settings, my template is `about/_entry`, as it is in the tutorial.

The error I get is:

> ```
> HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
> Template not found: about
> ```

Maybe I missed a step? What should I look for?

Answer (score 2):

Templates or folder with an underscore are private and can't be accessed via template routing. Remove the `_` and you are fine. For example `news/entry` instead of `news/_entry`

Comment: Then why is `_entry` used in the tutorial?

Comment: Usually because those templates are not meant to be exposed to public routing. I usually never create public templates and keep all of them private

Comment: In the tutorial, those are public pages... I'm not understanding why it works there, but not for me.

Comment: Im sure they are not public. Otherwise they would not contain an underscore. Especially for seo purposes it makes no sense to have an url `news/_entry` those routes are usually only meant to be accessed via entry routes

Comment: In the tutorial, the route to the about page is just `about/`, and in the templates folder, the file is `about/_entry.twig`... Are you saying I should do it differently than the tutorial?

Comment: I never watched the tutorial but I'm pretty sure you misunderstood something. As you can see here https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html. The course probably talks about element request, not about template routing

Comment: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/#hidden-templates explains that we DO want the file to be hidden and with an underscore, and shows that it is accessible through the route like `about/` or `news/`

Comment: Well that paragraph explains exactly what I said. Those files can't be accessed via template routes only via element routing cause they are hidden and not public. So unless you have an element  that routes to this template it won't be triggert - and that's element routing

Comment: So I guess then my question is why is my element routing not working.

Comment: You might've missed the part where we created a Structure section (called About) for the pages and use the templates to render this entries. If you create a new entry in the Structure section called "About" and then a child entry under it called "Locations" then you should be able to access the template via about/locations.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing your Uri structure and without your element slug

Comment: Oh, it looks like I got it. I missed the part where the slug for the About entry was changed... Thanks for all your help, guys.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the video but just reading you I think that he may be using a layout file in the tutorial and use the `_templates` as includes. So inside a master template:

```
{% include "about/_entry" %}
```

Or... if you have `index.twig` with:

```twig
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your site</h1>
    {% block content %}
        <p>You shouldn't see me</p>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And `about/_entry.twig` with:

```twig
{% block content %}
    Hello or {{entry.title}} if you have content in there
{% endblock %}
```

That would work also... I may also be reading you completely wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I problem was that I missed the part where the slug for the About Craft Coffee entry was changed. In video 26, Creating a Structure Section, at 2:58, the slug `about-crafty-coffee` was changed to just `about`. He did it real quick, and I had to go back and watch the whole video to notice that. I should have rewatched it sooner. So that's why my element routing was not working; there wasn't an entry that matched the slug, because I hadn't changed mine.